# Soldering basic mini LED dual flasher kit from instructions

Tags: soldering

I need help how to make this flasher work. I am fairly new to soldering and circuitry. This is the image.

all parts:

[image]

just the circuit board:

[image]

I tried doing it without soldering, is this right?

[image]

This is the only assembly instructions they gave us.

[image]

Comment: The upper transistor is backwards, the case needs to match the case outline on the PWB. The capacitors and LEDs must be installed in a specific direction, I can't tell by the picture if they are correct.

Comment: @Mattman944 Thank you! And I'm pretty sure that I got the capacitors in the right direction because there's positive and negative written on board and capacitors. But for LED, it does not show that on the LED light. Is it safe to say that the smaller tale is negative and the longer one is positive?

Comment: Yes, the longer LED lead is positive. The flat side of the package, if it has one, is negative. The larger metal piece inside the plastic is usually negative.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification!!

Comment: LEDs have a flat side as well as having legs of different lengths.  The outlines on the board for the LEDs show the flat sides.